# How to declare function with anonymous enum in function signature?

Tags: c, enums

One can have a function that contains an anonymous enum in its signature. However, when i tried moving function signature to the header file, i have encountered a compiler errors.

```
void myfunct (enum {a=1} param); 
void myfunct (enum {a=1} param)
{}
```

That yields the following:

> error: conflicting types for ‘myfunct’

If enum is named (and moved outside of the function declaration), there is no error.

What would be a correct syntax to use?

Comment: Use a named enum. You can never have two anonymous enums be considered the same type.

Comment: Types created in prototype scope are unique to that prototype (and hence essentially worthless, and are always a de facto mistake, even though the language allows you to do it — but a good compiler warns you about the error of your ways).  You also can't usefully write: `extern void function(struct newname *p);` and later define `struct newname { … };` because the two types are unrelated.  You need at least `struct newname;` before the prototype — then it works sanely.  Or, of course, the full structure definition.

Comment: An `enum` type with a single enumerated value is moderately pointless, incidentally.  I'll assume that was a mild case of 'over-minimization'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do that, obviously

[Standard C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.2.4 Storage durations of objects**
>
> 16. An enumeration comprises a set of named integer constant values. Each distinct
>     enumeration constitutes a different enumerated type.

but you can use named one

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum my_enum
{
    a,
    b,
    c,
    MY_ENUM_MAX
};

void func(enum my_enum value)
{
    printf("%d\n", value);
}

int main(void)
{
    func(a);
    func(b);
}
```

or you can typedef it

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum
{
    a,
    b,
    c,
    MY_ENUM_MAX
}my_enum;

void func (my_enum value)
{
    printf("%d\n", value);
}

int main(void)
{
    func(a);
    func(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments:

> Use a named enum. You can never have two anonymous enums be considered the same type.

Edit this post if something can be added to make it more useful or clear.